# Mongo $filter with date comparison

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregation which has a date comparison where I only want to grab documents that have the `$$item.date` less than the current time.

```
[
    { $match : { "_id" : "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e" } },
    { $project : {
            "fulfillments" : {
                $filter : {
                    "input" : "$fulfillments",
                    "as" : "item",
                    "cond" : { "$gte" : ["$$item.date","new Date()"]}
                }
            }
        }
    },

    ...

    ...
]
```

The important part that I have a question about above is the following:

`"cond" : { "$gte" : ["$$item.date","new Date()"]}`

This doesn't seem to be working as I can change the `new Date()` to `1` or `0` or pretty much any value and it still returns all documents. I need it to only return documents that have the `date` greater than or equal to the current date.

For example, given the following document

```
{
  "_id": "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e",
  "fulfillments": [
    {
      "_id": "582deb33bb117300010a2ae5",
      "date": new Date("2016-11-23T17:00:00-0700"),
    },
    {
      "_id": "582deb33bdf17300010a2ae5",
      "date": new Date("2017-11-23T17:00:00-0700"),
    }
}
```

Only the following `fulfillment` should be returned because it is `2017-11-23`

```
    {
      "_id": "582deb33bdf17300010a2ae5",
      "date": new Date("2017-11-23T17:00:00-0700"),
    }
```

**Update**
There is question if I am giving an accurate document strucutre, so I included a screenshot below to validate this.

[image]

Comment: I think its the quotes around new Date that is the problem.

Comment: @Veeram when I try without quotes, at least in IDE and in golang, its required.

Comment: Remove the quote around `new Date()`:  `{ "$gte" : ["$$item.date", new Date()]}`

Comment: @Styvane - I have tried running without and it does not work.

Comment: are you trying to run this query in mongo shell or from golang ?

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([     { $match : { "_id" : "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e" } },     { $project : {             "fulfillments" : {                 $filter : {                     "input" : "$fulfillments",                     "as" : "item",                     "cond" : { "$gte" : ["$$item.date",new Date()]}                 }             }         }     }])` works beautifully. Please double check your documents structure.

Comment: @Styvane I plugged in your exact query and same result. I have updated OP to show the document structure I specified is valid.

Comment: Do you mind adding the code that you used to create the document structure ? I mean the insert query and schema structure . I think it's worth looking into it.

Comment: @TheJediCowboy you started your question with *... grab documents that have the $$item.date less than the current time*  then later said in the same question *...I need it to only return documents that have the date greater than or equal to the current date* What is your real intention?  I am sure your are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the current time on the machine just remove the `"` from the query, see below for my example

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e",
        "fulfillments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "582deb33bb117300010a2ae5",
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-11-24T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "582deb33bdf17300010a2ae5",
                        "date" : ISODate("2017-11-24T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
>
> db.test.aggregate([
...     { $match : { "_id" : "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e" } },
...     { $project : {
...             "fulfillments" : {
...                 $filter : {
...                     "input" : "$fulfillments",
...                     "as" : "item",
...                     "cond" : { "$gte" : ["$$item.date",new Date()]}
...                 }
...             }
...         }
...     }
... ]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "57b4c5f0291ebb13110b888e",
        "fulfillments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "582deb33bdf17300010a2ae5",
                        "date" : ISODate("2017-11-24T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
>
```